# What are best practices for where to answer agency specific Open Data Policy implementation questions?

Tags: releasing-data, best-practice

USAID recently launched a [Frequently Asked Questions page](http://www.usaid.gov/data/frequently-asked-questions) to handle Q&A concerning their policy [ADS 579](http://www.usaid.gov/ads/policy/500/579).

These Q&As are directed at both internal and external audiences.

I could see posting the questions on this site, but based on the questions, it seems appropriate to have them on USAID's website.

How have others approached this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a "depends" question, but i'll lean to always having the answers on your site. you are the authority. you are releasing the data. you are in control.
bringing them here could help alert people to the data and the questions, as well as help crowd source solutions or answers you are seeking.
there's a saying called "own your data" and i believe this falls under it as well.

Answer (score 2):

The Open Data Stack Exchange is a fine place for free asking of questions. FAQs are usually edited and distilled, so there's really no conflict. USAID can harvest common questions from here and post answers on an FAQ on their site, or they can point to the answers here, depending on institutional preferences.

Comment: there can be conflicts, especially if a group is pushing their q&a onto another group, instead of taking care of it themselves. also, docs/q&a are going to be generally more resourceful/helpful on the site, rather than sending users somewhere else.  not saying don't do it, just think there are positives and negatives to everything

Answer (score 1):

Do what is easiest, I think. Getting authority to let people post questions on usaid.gov is problematic at best. Here it is a little more informal.